# Launching shell script from SSH and disconnect

Tags: ssh, scripting, remote

I have a script which I run from SSH that launches several processes which I would like to keep open when I disconnect from my session.

Is that feasible? Launching the script in background is not a solution....

**UPDATE**

My script launches a java process with a different classpath and calls other 4 scripts, each of them launching different java processes with different classpaths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the processes are somewhat interactive / not suitable for running as daemons, you're looking for something like [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) - both of them allow you to start a session with multiple windows in them and detach and reattach that session:

```
tmux new-session session-1
# start an application
C-b d # C-b means Ctrl-b
# You're now back in your terminal and can disconnect from the server
# After connecting again, use
tmux attach -t session-1
# to get back to your previously created session.
```

The workflow for screen is similar but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Comment: which of the one do you suggest?

Comment: I personally use tmux, although the differences between the both of them for non-fancy use cases are really quite small.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what does the "keep open" mean. If you mean you'd like to *reconnect* some time later and see the output and interact, then Wieland has already provided you a good advice. If you just want them keep running when you exit, you might want to try using `nohup`: it may be a foreground or background, and it will do the trick.

Comment: keep each of the subscripts and respective java processes running

Comment: Then please try `nohup`: it's just a simple wrapper around your custom command you run. It will redirect the output to a file (`nohup.out` by default, it may appear possible to specify some other file, please check your particular version manual) and it will save the command from being stopped upon terminal disconnection (by blocking the _HUP_ signal).

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Wieland's answer, you would use GNU Screen this way :

```
screen -S session-name
# start your application here
C-a d # C-a means Ctrl and "a" key. 'd' stands for 'detach'
# You're now back in your terminal and can disconnect from the server

# After connecting again, use
screen -r session-name
# to get back to your previously created session.
```

Comment: awesome. If I physically go on my server, can I also retrieve the session?

Comment: Yes, assuming you're using a user that has rw on the session file saved (typically) under `/tmp`, a.k.a. the same user or root, usually.